# ESlint global install mac root terminal error

Tags: javascript, npm, eslint

Im trying to globally install ESlint on my mac running mojave 10.14.6 but everytime i run 'npm install -g eslint' i get this error:

`The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).`

Is there anyway to run terminal with root/admin permissions?

Comment: If you are on Windows, right-click the application and click "Run as Administrator"

Comment: @Rojo he clearly states he's on Mac Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `sudo npm install -g eslint` and entering your password?

Comment: @Vidarsskjalf please upvote this answer for other's who come across this issue in the future.